# Wash out gem add http_basic_authenticate_with occur an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wash-out

this is my error stack :

```
> TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
>     
>     activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/security_utils.rb:23:in `digest'
 lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71:in `block in
    > http_basic_authenticate_with'
```

and here is my code:

```
 http_basic_authenticate_with username: "xxx01", password: "123456"
```

when i comment the code ,it works, i don't know why this error occured,how to fix it

it works when i first enter the page, but when i input the username and password the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

i knew it now, http_basic_auth only accept :name & :passowrd